# MSMQ: What is the best way to read a queue in a non-blocking fashion?

Tags: msmq

If a queue is empty and you don't want to block for too long, you risk getting a System.Messaging.MessageQueueException.

How would you tell the difference between a timeout on waiting for a message and a real error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MessageQueueException.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5te2tk0.aspx for a sample similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked that property.